# Moment.js - Displaying historical data from selected range with regard of user timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, mariadb, dst

I'm really confused about correctly displaying historical data:

**What i have:**

- Database records stored in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" format and in UTC+0 (MariaDB - DateTime type)
- Web application (using moment.js) which allows users to pick range between two dates (without time of day part)

**What i need:**

- To fetch records from selected range but taking into account the time zone of the current user (so for example he chooses records only from 23 March: in DB i have a record from 22 March, but in user local timezone it was already 23 March, so if I'm thinking correctly, he needs to see that record too)
- To handle the DST bullshit correctly
- To display dates in result records in correct local time of user (as it was on that moment in past)

I'm hoping for some kind of guide that will explain to me what steps i have to take to achieve all of this. Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide the base of what you're working with. Minimally, the from and to date fields, the date format you're using and the expected results. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define two variables in your client-side code:

```
var startTime = moment().startOf('day').utc().format();
var untilTime = moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').utc().format();
```

You now have the range for your query in terms of UTC.  Send them to the server via form post or whatever mechanism you have, then run the query.

When you query, use a half-open range: `recordTime >= startTime AND recordTime < untilTime`

When you bring the results back down to the client, you will have them in terms of UTC, so convert to local time like so:

```
moment.utc(theData).local().format()
```

Adjust input/output format as desired.

Comment: Thanks, but what about situation like this one:

1. record on db has date "2016-06-06 23:00:00". 

2. when that event occured, in user local time (lets say utc+2) there was already 07 of June - "2016-06-07 01:00:00". 

So, when picking a date to view that record, he would choose 2016-06-07, not 2016-06-06 and the record will not show up...
I know that i can add or substract specific offset, depending on user timezone, before query for records, but what about DST? How can i know what offset to choose then?

Comment: The code I gave will already handle this.  When you run `moment()` on the client-side, you are working in local mode, including any time zone offset and DST that may be in effect.  You calculate the extents of the day in local time, then convert them to UTC.  On the server side, you must do a range query.  With the example you gave, the range would be from `2016-06-07 00:00:00` until `2016-06-08 00:00:00` local time, which would be from `2016-06-06 23:00:00` until `2016-06-07 23:00:00` UTC.  It *must* be a range query.  You cannot check for exact equality by calendar date.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, store into `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME`.

`TIMESTAMP` converts the date+time to be inserted according to the client's timezone into UTC for storage.  A subsequent `SELECT` reconverts, based on the reader's timezone.

That way, no code will be needed to achieve the goal (as I perceive it).

Comment: This doesn't help, as the time zone is that of the user on the other end of a web browser - not the user account that is connecting to the database.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` is probably still a good choice though, just the conversion between UTC and session time zone doesn't help the problem unless the session time zone is set accordingly, and getting that from the user can be a pain.

Comment: If you want to freeze the TZ when storing the datetime, then use `DATETIME`.  (Think of `DATETIME` as being a picture of a local clock.)  Now I don't understand the original question.